# python JSON for loop

Tags: python, json, data-science

every time i run it it gives me only the last value of social_score, while I want to get all the social_score values in the json API and store the output to an #iterated list to calculate with the valueI

> help on this JSON
>
> ```
> url = requests.get("https://api2.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&symbol=xrp&data_points=730&interval=day&change=max").json()
>
> def get_data():
>     for data in url['data']:
>         result = data['social_score']
>         print(result)
>         
> get_data()
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the intermediate results in a list variable:

```
url = requests.get("https://api2.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&symbol=xrp&data_points=730&interval=day&change=max").json()

def get_data():
    results = []
    for data in url['data']:
        result = data['social_score']
        results.append(result)
    return results
        
result = get_data()
```

Comment: that was so helpful. But yet it only returns the last value of social_score instead of returning them all, help in regard to that.

Comment: You would want to inspected more on the format of `data` JSON. `url['data']` only contains one dictionary, which in your case, is the XRP social score in _one particular timepoint_. That's why it is returning only one timepoint. After looking at the JSON returned from the API request, I see that to get a list of XRP social scores over time, you should retrieve `"social_score"` from `data["timeseries"]` instead of `data["social_score"]`. The way to retrieve this is to replace the whole for loop into `results = [t['social_score'] for t in data['timeseries']]`. The for loop is not even needed.

Comment: Remarks: this is already beyond the original problem context.

Comment: thanks, bro I finally got it, really appreciate the support